# A question on the procedure of finding the matrix of a linear transformation of a polynomial and a combination of its derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, transformation

I'm trying to self-study Linear Algebra from Linear Algebra Done Wrong, but the book doesn't have solution manual so my question might be extremely easy, apologize in advance:

The question is for the linear transformation below find its matrix:

$T:\mathbb{P_n}\rightarrow\mathbb{P_n};Tf(t)=2f(t)+3f^{'}(t)-4f^{''}(t)$ with respect to the standard basis $1,t,t^2,...,t^n$.

Firstly, I defined $\mathbf{e}_0:=1;\mathbf{e}_1:=t;...;\mathbf{e}_n:=t^n$ for the polynomial, and then I reduced the transformation to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kT(\mathbf{e}_k)$ and then I evaluated $T(\mathbf{e}_k)$ for all $k$. For example $T(\mathbf{e}_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
\vdots\\  
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ and so on until $T(\mathbf{e}_n)=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
\vdots\\  
-4n(n-1)\\ 
3n\\ 
2\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$. After that, I returned to the $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kT(\mathbf{e}_k)$, factored out the $a_k$ and got the matrix:$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & -8 & \cdots  & 0\\ 
0 & 2 & 6 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -4n(n-1)\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 3n\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, Is my reasoning correct? If it isn't, where's the problem and how one could solve this solution and if it is, Is this the usual way to derive the matrix or there's a simpler way to do that? Is the matrix correct after all? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess you mean $T(\bf{e}_0)$ rather than $T(\bf{e}_1)$ in line six. BTW you can use `\bf` instead of `\mathbf`. Apart from that, your derivation and solution looks just fine.

Comment: Thanks and corrected it. So what's the use of doing derivatives like this? It seems that the purpose of doing derivatives like this is to say derivatives can be considered as a linear transformation and that alone; Or is there a situation where doing derivatives like this is better than the regular way?

Comment: The use of this particular matrix, I do not really know. Regarding using the property that differentiating can be considered a linear transformation in a vector space of functions is a much broader question, though. Linear algebra shows up everywhere and I am not enough of an expert to give you nearly a full account of its range in differential problems.